# Bootstrap JS not working in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running into an issue where the Javascript portions of Bootstrap aren't working with my Rails app.  For instance, the code below should use the [Bootstrap version of the popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), however, I'm just getting a basic tooltip to appear when I hover over my link.  What am I missing?

[image: what is showing up]

**GemFile**

```
gem "bootstrap-sass"
```

**application.js**

```
//= require modernizr
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.cookie
//= require jquery.piechart
//= require jquery.dlmenu
//= require jquery.tooltipster
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require mithril
//= require_tree .
```

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*= require font-awesome.min
*= require tooltipster
*= require_self
*/

@import "normalize";
@import "util";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "fonts";
@import "app";
@import "media-queries";
@import "login";
@import "header";
@import "alerts";
@import "hero";
@import "feedback";
@import "reports";
@import "main-content";
@import "popovers";
@import "push-menus";
@import "footer";
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<a tabindex="0" role="button" 
  data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" 
  title="Severity Score" data-content="Severity score is...">
  <%= image_tag("tooltips/tooltip-question.png") %>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [enable popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage) via JS:

Template (added `class` but you can use `id` or whatever):

```
<a class="popover" tabindex="0" role="button" 
  data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" 
  title="Severity Score" data-content="Severity score is...">
  <%= image_tag("tooltips/tooltip-question.png") %>
</a>
```

JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.popover').popover();
});
```

If you plan to use the same options for all popovers, you can use the following selector:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({placement: 'right'});
```

Comment: Yup, that does the trick.  I thought the HTML5 `data-toggle` was supposed to make it work without having to do the JS though.